# How to import products images from external url in magento 1.7.0?

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I want to import some products images in 'media/import' directory from a external source url in magento 1.7 version. Someone please help me !

Comment: hey guys ..nobody knows it? please please help me .

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example

```
$image_location = getDownloadImage("product",$image_url);               
if ( file_exists($image_location) ) {
    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($image_location,array('thumbnail','small_image','image'),true,false);
}

    // Download Image
    public function  getDownloadImage($type,$file){
        $path = str_replace("index.php","",$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);        
        $import_location = $path.'media/catalog/';
        if (!file_exists($import_location)){
            mkdir($import_location, 0755);
        }
        $import_location = $path.'media/catalog/'.$type.'/';
        if (!file_exists($import_location)){
            mkdir($import_location, 0755);
        }

        // todo check if last character has /

        $file_source = Mage::getStoreConfig('oscommerceimportconf/oscconfiguration/conf_imageurl',Mage::app()->getStore()).$file;
        $file_target = $import_location."/".basename($file);

        $file_path = "";
        if (($file != '') and (!file_exists($file_target))){
            $rh = fopen($file_source, 'rb');
            $wh = fopen($file_target, 'wb');
            if ($rh===false || $wh===false) {
                // error reading or opening file
                $file_path = "";
            }
            while (!feof($rh)) {
                if (fwrite($wh, fread($rh, 1024)) === FALSE) {
                    $file_path = $file_target;
                }
            }
            fclose($rh);
            fclose($wh);
        }
        if (file_exists($file_target)){
            if ($type == 'category'){
                $file_path = $file;
            }else{
                $file_path = $file_target;
            }           
        }

        return $file_path;
    }               }
```

Comment: thanks for replying me, would you please tell me in which file I have to add/change this code

Answer (score 0):

As I know default Magento import does not allow to import images from remote URLs. You need to download them from those URLS to 'media/import' directory at your FTP. Then to assign images to products in your Magento import file indicate image name for each products (with slash at the beginning - e.g. /imagename.jpg ). 
If you need to import images directly from URL without saving them first, you cay look for some script to do the task. Other way via extension. I know the one that allows to do it - Store Manager for Magento, but its paid.

Comment: I have a csv file in which there is a column for image url. I want some script in pho that check for each record in that column and download it and save it with a custom name locally.